# git pull over ssh in Windows client hangs after starting to use a token

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using Windows ssh native server (comes with RS4).
My clients are both Windows and Linux.

I used to git pull from ssh (Windows/Linux) to Windows machines all the time with no issue.
Today I started using a token over https and from that point on I can't git pull using ssh, the process simply hangs forever in both Windows and Linux clients.

git pull locally works fine, other git pull functions (like config/remote/etc.) works over ssh without any issue.

I've also tried to run a python script over ssh that execute git pull on the remote machine and that didn't work as well, it hangs also.

In the remote's task manager I see bunch of git processes like: git-credential-manager.exe, git.exe, git-remote-https.exe - meaning there's a need to interact with one of those programs but they are running in the background cause they were launched over ssh.

If I do:

```
git pull https://user:password@github.com/path/repo
```

it works but I don't want to use plain text passwords in my code.
How I can get around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs due to git-credential-manager.exe (that is part of Git for Windows) is popping out in the background of the remote machine during ssh session.

To solve this you should disable git-credential-manager by uninstall it/don't install in in the first place during Git for Windows installation/run following git command:

```
config --global --unset credential.helper
```

This will disable the credential helper globally. 
If you want to save the password in .git-credential file (like in Linux) run:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

The '.git-credential' file will be created in your home directory in the first time you will enter your password.

SSH will no longer hangs.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to deploy RunDeck node and encountered a similar case. Actually I also changed the config in c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig and the issue was resolved.